# Composer validate fault for develop version like this 0.0.1-dev

Tags: validation, version, composer-php

I use the version field in composer.json. When I write the version in this format **0.0.1-dev**, this is not valid with composer validate. This format, however, is valid according to the [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version).

What can I do to ensure that the development version is valid?

Comment: I use the version number in this section:

    "description": "...",
    "version": "0.0.1-dev",
    "autoload": {

Answer (score 0):

Composer validate doesn't give me any errors when using `0.0.1-dev` as a version.

You can try `0.0.1@dev` or `^0.0.1@dev`.

Comment: Thanks, i have it tested. It is also not valid.

Comment: Yes you have right. I had forgot to update the project. Now it works.